# Swig Wrappers use deleted default constructor

Tags: c++, swig

I am trying to generate a C# wrapper for the following C++ class using Swig 4.0.2

```
#include "TypeDefs.h"

namespace Image
{
    class ImageRange : public range<numImages_t>
    {

        public:

        ImageRange(const ImageRange&) noexcept;
        ImageRange(ImageRange&&) noexcept;

        ImageRange() = delete;
        ~ImageRange() noexcept;
        ImageRange(numImages_t start, numImages_t end);
        
        ImageRange getOverlap(const ImageRange& that) const;
    };
}
```

As you can see, the ImageRange default constructor is deleted. The created cxx file for the method getOverlap(const ImageRange& that) is not compiling, as it uses the default constructor to create the result object.

```
SWIGEXPORT void * SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_ImageRange_getOverlap(void * jarg1, void * jarg2) {
  void * jresult ;
  Image::ImageRange *arg1 = (Image::ImageRange *) 0 ;
  Image::ImageRange *arg2 = 0 ;
  Image::ImageRange result;
  
  arg1 = (Image::ImageRange *)jarg1; 
  arg2 = (Image::ImageRange *)jarg2;
  if (!arg2) {
    SWIG_CSharpSetPendingExceptionArgument(SWIG_CSharpArgumentNullException, "Image::ImageRange const & type is null", 0);
    return 0;
  } 
  result = ((Image::ImageRange const *)arg1)->getOverlap((Image::ImageRange const &)*arg2);
  jresult = new Image::ImageRange((const Image::ImageRange &)result); 
  return jresult;
}
```

How can I prevent to create non compiling code like this with Swig?
The header file I'm using should stay unmodified, as it is delivered from third party

Interface file:

```
%module TestInterop

%nodefaultctor Image::ImageRange;

%include "typemaps.i"
%include "arrays_csharp.i"
%include "windows.i"
%include "std_vector.i"
%include "cpointer.i"
%include "std_string.i"
namespace std {
   %template(vectorf) vector<float>;
   %template(vectori) vector<int>;
};
%apply unsigned long long { size_t }


%include "include\TypeDefs.h"

%include "include\Geometry.h"
%include "include\Range.h"
%include "include\ImageRange.h"
```

command line:

```
swig -c++ -csharp -outdir ..\TestInterop\Source -dllimport TestInterop.dll Wrapper.i
```

Comment: To help us better help you, please post your `.i` file

Comment: I've added the interface file

Comment: Can you also provide your command line arguments to swig?

Comment: sure, I've added the command line arguments

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an open swig bug: https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/1644

The  `%nodefaultctor` directive is *supposed* to take care of this:

```
%nodefaultctor Image::ImageRange;
```

[Docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn8)

However, the result is that SWIG indeed continues to declare a default-constructed instance of `ImageRange`:

```
SWIGEXPORT void * SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_ImageRange_getOverlap(void * jarg1, void * jarg2) {
    void * jresult ;
    Image::ImageRange *arg1 = (Image::ImageRange *) 0 ;
    Image::ImageRange *arg2 = 0 ;
    Image::ImageRange result;
    // ...
```

What I recommend you do to work around this is to tell swig to ignore you method, and then implement your own wrapper around `getOverlap` that returns a pointer:

```
%module TestInterop
// ...
%nodefaultctor Image::ImageRange;
%ignore Image::ImageRange::getOverlap;
%include "include\ImageRange.h"
%rename("getOverlap") Image::ImageRange::getOverlap;
%newobject Image::ImageRange::getOverlap;
%extend Image::ImageRange
{
    ImageRange* getOverlap(const ImageRange& that) const
    {
        return new ImageRange($self->getOverlap(that));
    }
}
```

This gives us the appropriate SWIG wrapper code:

```
SWIGEXPORT void * SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_ImageRange_getOverlap(void * jarg1, void * jarg2) {
  void * jresult ;
  Image::ImageRange *arg1 = (Image::ImageRange *) 0 ;
  Image::ImageRange *arg2 = 0 ;
  Image::ImageRange *result = 0 ;
```

---

Just remember to have the `%newobject Image::ImageRange::getOverlap;` directive in place so that the C# layer takes appropriate ownership of the returned pointer; SWIG assumes by default that returned pointers from C++ are owned by the C++ layer.

If you get it wrong, you'll see in the generated `ImageRange.cs` that SWIG passes `false` for the `swigCMemOwn` boolean upon constructing the Proxy C# `ImageRange` object.

Here's what `getOverlap` should look like in the C# for reference:

```
public ImageRange getOverlap(ImageRange that) {
  global::System.IntPtr cPtr = TestInteropPINVOKE.ImageRange_getOverlap(swigCPtr, ImageRange.getCPtr(that));
  ImageRange ret = (cPtr == global::System.IntPtr.Zero) ? null : new ImageRange(cPtr, true);
  if (TestInteropPINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Pending) throw TestInteropPINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Retrieve();
  return ret;
}
```

---

We use the `%ignore` directive before including our header so that SWIG doesn't generate a wrapper for the version of `getOverlap` inside of the header:

```
%ignore Image::ImageRange::getOverlap;
```

Then, afterwards we use the rename directive to un-ignore it (just renaming it back to itself). This is so that we don't ignore our class extension method we declare later.

```
%rename("getOverlap") Image::ImageRange::getOverlap;
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this before, and now again. But it has no effect on the output for this method. It still creates the object with implicitly calling the default constructor. I'm not sure, if this is not the correct approach or the directive does simply not apply

Comment: @exbachi: Updated my answer. Sorry for the delay; life got in the way